# Open Source Application for Android to send messages

Tags: android, open-source, sms, message

I need an open source application to send messages in android devices which i can extend for my thesis.
Do you know any open source such as that?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are open source applications that are dedicated to sending messages. Few of them are

1.SMSDroid
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ub0r.android.smsdroid&hl=en
https://github.com/felixb/smsdroid

2.TextSecure
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms&hl=en
https://github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure

Comment: Note that TextSecure does not use SMS. This may or may not be relevant in this case, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Can we use GPLv3 project monetize via ads ang upload to Android market? Of course i have to modify it for another purpose..